# Keyframe fades in, but how do I make it fade out on click?

Tags: css, sass

I'm using keyframes so fade in the items on click, but I want them to then fade out when I click again. How do I do this with keyframes? Maybe this is something you can't actually do with keyframes?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/mattmcgilton/pen/jOMGmyG)

```
<div class="icon-wrap" onclick="bunAnimate(this)">
    click me
</div>
<div class="primary__nav">
  <ul id="primary" class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

```
.primary__nav {
   display: none;

  &.open {
   display: block;
  }
}

.icon-wrap {
  cursor: pointer;
}
   
ul {
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    li {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: fadeInRight 0.5s linear forwards;
    animation: fadeInRight 0.5s linear forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.35s;
    animation-delay: 0.35s;
    }

    li:nth-of-type(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
    }

    li:nth-of-type(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.45s;
    animation-delay: 0.45s;
    }

    li:nth-of-type(4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
    }

    li:nth-of-type(5) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.55s;
    animation-delay: 0.55s;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```
function bunAnimate(x) {
  $(".icon-wrap").toggleClass("open");
  $(".primary__nav").toggleClass("open");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the list fade out item by item on click by more-or-less reversing the process.

There is one slight problem though, it's not possible to do this entirely in CSS as animations will not set the display property, so we can't get a keyframes declaration to set `display: none` on the primary nav element when the fading out has all completed. We get round this by introducing another class, `display`, which we call through Javascript. This is done rather crudely with a `setTimeout`, it may be possible to be more sophisticated by listening for the end of an animation, but it basically comes to the same thing.

```js
function bunAnimate(x) {
  document.querySelector(".icon-wrap").classList.toggle("open");
  if (!document.querySelector(".primary__nav").matches('.open')) { 
    document.querySelector(".primary__nav").classList.add("open");
    document.querySelector(".primary__nav").classList.add('display'); //display immediately it's open
  }
  else {
    document.querySelector(".primary__nav").classList.remove("open"); 
    setTimeout(function () {
      document.querySelector(".primary__nav").classList.remove("display");     
      },550);//unpleasant but animations don't allow setting of display
  }
}
```

```css
.primary__nav {
   display: none;
}

.primary__nav.display{
   display: block;
}

.icon-wrap {
  cursor: pointer;
}
   
ul {
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    
  li {
    animation-name: fadeOutLeft;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

  li:nth-of-type(1) {
    animation-delay: 0.55s;
    }
    
  li:nth-of-type(2) {
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
    }

  li:nth-of-type(3) {
    animation-delay: 0.45s;
    }

  li:nth-of-type(4) {
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
    }
    
  li:nth-of-type(5) {
    animation-delay: 0.35s;
    }
    
 .open li {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    animation-name: fadeInRight;
    }
    
  .open li:nth-of-type(1) {
    animation-delay: 0.35s;
    }
    
  .open li:nth-of-type(2) {
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
    }

  .open li:nth-of-type(3) {
    animation-delay: 0.45s;
    }

  .open li:nth-of-type(4) {
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
    }

  .open li:nth-of-type(5) {
    animation-delay: 0.55s;
    }

@keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeOutLeft {
  0% {
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-wrap" onclick="bunAnimate(this)">
    click me
</div>
<div class="primary__nav">
  <ul id="primary" class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Note: I used pure CSS as I'm not familiar with SCSS.